# Java with JSON Questions

Tags: java, json

I want to do an app in java (not java EE) that connects to an JSON API and retrieves some numbers from an serve. The problem is that i cannot find any good tutorial or information on this... is this possible to do only with java and if needed some libraries?

If so which and how do you do it using JSON?

This is an example of what i wanna do in JAVA with JSON but in PHP:

```
function api_query($method, array $req = array()) {
        // API settings
        $key = ''; // your API-key
        $secret = ''; // your Secret-key

        $req['method'] = $method;
        $mt = explode(' ', microtime());
        $req['nonce'] = $mt[1];

        // generate the POST data string
        $post_data = http_build_query($req, '', '&');

        $sign = hash_hmac("sha512", $post_data, $secret);

        // generate the extra headers
        $headers = array(
                'Sign: '.$sign,
                'Key: '.$key,
        );

        // our curl handle (initialize if required)
        static $ch = null;
        if (is_null($ch)) {
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Cryptsy API PHP client; '.php_uname('s').'; PHP/'.phpversion().')');
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.test.com/api');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

        // run the query
        $res = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($res === false) throw new Exception('Could not get reply: '.curl_error($ch));
        $dec = json_decode($res, true);
        if (!$dec) throw new Exception('Invalid data received, please make sure connection is working and requested API exists');
        return $dec;
}

$result = api_query("getinfo");

//$result = api_query("getmarkets");

//$result = api_query("mytransactions");

//$result = api_query("markettrades", array("marketid" => 26));

//$result = api_query("marketorders", array("marketid" => 26));

//$result = api_query("mytrades", array("marketid" => 26, "limit" => 1000));

//$result = api_query("allmytrades");

//$result = api_query("myorders", array("marketid" => 26));

//$result = api_query("allmyorders");

//$result = api_query("createorder", array("marketid" => 26, "ordertype" => "Sell", "quantity" => 1000, "price" => 0.00031000));

//$result = api_query("cancelorder", array("orderid" => 139567));

$result = api_query("calculatefees", array("ordertype" => 'Buy', 'quantity' => 1000, 'price' => '0.005'));

echo "<pre>".print_r($result, true)."</pre>";
```

i would appreciate any help ...

Comment: Tutorial might help : http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-json-tutorials/

Comment: This question also may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of great libraries to do this in Java. I would recommend jersey. Look here for a small tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/

If you want to write the communication yourself, you should at least use a library for parsing JSON. Check out https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). It's a pretty neat library that let's you treat JSON in an object oriented way.

Also take a look at [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) for making http requests.

Here's a [Gson tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) and here's a [HttpClient tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheHttpClient/article.html)